# ory hydra add prefix to access token

Tags: token, prefix, hydra

For a private project I am looking for the possibility to add a prefix to the tokens.

Like

```
Bearer {{prefix}} token
```

At the moment ory hydra runs in a docker container. Unfortunately I can't find an enviroment variable to set the prefix.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Hi, I don't have ORY Hydra knowledge, but I can suggest searching how to interpolate.

Comment: @IamMHussain: First of all, thank you very much for your time and also for your suggestion. The problem here. In ory hydra the tokens are stored in the database. The tokens are created in oAuth2 context (.../oauth2/auth and .../oauht2/token). I thought there is an enviroment variable somewhere that writes the token + prefix to the database when it is created. I.e. globally defined. But thanks for your suggestion.